# Unable to delegate textfield with UipickerView in SWIFT

Tags: swift, delegates, keyboard, uipickerview

i'm currently facing a problem in swift.
I implemented a method to make textfield next responder on returnkey tap, and o make it fonctional i have to make my textfields delegate (everything work on my other class).

The problem is, i also implemented a UIPickerView , which appear when "textfieldcategorie" is tapped, this pickerview need to be delegate, to put the choosen value in the textfield.

by the way, the method to make textfield nextresponder not working anymore, at the moment where i put the textfield in delegate , it become inactive.

this is the code is used :

declaration of my variable :

```
    @IBOutlet var textfieldcategorie: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var keyword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var codepostal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var prix: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var pickercategorie: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
```

The method to show uipickerview on tap :

```
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            pickercategorie.hidden = false
            return false
        }
```

The method to make textfield nextresponder :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //delegate method
    if textField == keyword {
    textfieldcategorie.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

    return true


}
```

}

I don't know if it's important, but i also use theses methods :

to move up the textfield when the keyboard appears :

```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: 25)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: 25)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    var movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0,  movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
//Fin Monter la vue lorsque le clavier apparait
```

And to dismiss the keyboard on tap anywhere in the view:

```
func DismissKeyboard(){
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I feel you must change your code as follows:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //delegate method
    if textField === keyword {
        textfieldcategorie.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

The reason being == operator checks equality of two objects but === operator check identity of two objects i.e. wether these two refer to the same object.

Also pleas change:

```
@IBOutlet var pickercategorie: UIPickerView!
```

Comment: I tried, now when i click on keyword the UIpicker appears instead to open keyboard.

Comment: no, sorry maybe I misspoke, i just want my textfield delegate work, because as i have the pickerview delegate, when i try to make my textfield delegate too, they become inactive, and by the way the method to moveup the view or to make textfield next repsonder doesn't work anymore